# Pl upload library reference

Tags: reactjs, plupload

I am working on some POC or code where in I am trying to integrate Pl upload to my react application.

I found very good example -
This one is very good, wrapper for listening all the events from Pl upload library.

https://github.com/lemonCMS/react-plupload

I could integrate it fine, however I noticed linking of Pl upload happened in the index.html file (Which is not ideal way.).

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/plupload/3.1.2/plupload.full.min.js' async></script>
```

Need some input, how can I link same library coping inside my project directory.
So here basically I am expecting window.plupload should be initialized fine on load.

Another example I really liked is, as this will maintain state in the redux store and I hope I can navigate accross application with upload stays in progress.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-plupload

However for second example as well, need some input about linking.
Also, please suggest if i am missing anything.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all.

I have figured out, I had to install, below package.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/plupload

This is not latest version, but will solve my purpose.

Thank you!